# Object of type 'manifest' and path 'C:\CustomManifest.xml' cannot be created

Tags: manifest, msdeploy, webdeploy

I am struggling with msdeploy (aka Web Deploy). I have tried to create a simple manifest (from the example of [MSDN](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd569104%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)) :

```
<sitemanifest>
   <appHostConfig path="mySite" />
</sitemanifest>
```

Unfortunately, any command with this manifest as a source dies with the following message :

```
msdeploy -verb:dump -source:manifest=c:\CustomManifest.xml
Error: Object of type 'manifest' and path 'C:\CustomManifest.xml' cannot be created.
Error: One or more entries in the manifest 'sitemanifest' are not valid.
Error Code: ERROR_SITE_DOES_NOT_EXIST
More Information: Site 'mySite' does not exist.  Learn more at: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=221672#ERROR_SITE_DOES_NOT_EXIST.
Error count: 1.
```

Any Idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, finally understood my issue : a manifest is made only to export what you need. It is not made to generate something from scratch. To generate a web site, the package provider has to be used.

Comment: I know it's a little bit outdated question, but can you please specify what exactly you did to fix it?

Comment: it actually does not make sense to dump a manifest. What I would suggest you would be to publish a dummy web site using Visual Studio to a web deploy package and analyze the content of the generated manifest.